# Storing zips in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to store a zip file as a column in a SQL Server table. When I open this zip in notepad++, it has null characters in some places.

What datatype can I use for the SQL Server column to store this zip?

I have tried using `varchar`, `nvarchar`, `text` but they only store till they encounter the first nul character.

Comment: Your question is probably a duplicate, but in any case check out the various BLOB data types.

Comment: It's certainly not true that `varchar` et al can only store up until the first `nul`. Any such limitation is in the tool(s) that you're using to examine the stored data. E.g. `declare @t table (Val varchar(20))

insert into @t(Val) values ('abc' + CHAR(0) + 'def')

select LEN(Val),SUBSTRING(Val,5,1) from @t` returns `7` and `d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatype to use would be `varbinary(max)` which holds up to 2 GB of binary data.

The datatypes you've tried are only good for **text** data - not for **binary** data. And also: `text`, `ntext` and `image` datatypes have been deprecated with SQL Server 2005 - you definitely shouldn't be using those anymore

**PS:** also see Hossam's answer - if you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer, you could also investigate using the `FILESTREAM` feature of SQL Server to store the actual data contents of your blobs in the server's file system (instead of inside the database). This *can* improve performance quite significantly (if you use the file I/O streaming interface), but it does require a bit more work to get this to fly.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with @marc_s however I recommend using FILESTREAM as it will leverage the rich streaming APIs and performance.

you can check the following links for more details

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx

Comment: While I agree that FILESTREAM can be a useful feature, it's also quite a bit of work. If you use FILESTREAM, but access your files only through T-SQL or "classic" `SqlDataReader`, things are actually slower than without FILESTREAM. To leverage the speed of FILESTREAM, you must access the blobs stored in those columns using the `SqlFileStream` file streaming I/O interface, which definitely is more work.

Comment: @marc_s I agree with you however I think the final decision will depend on more details about the project like the importance of performance, file size,...